# Vala Gtk Folder selection

Tags: gtk, vala

I'm creating a simple GTK+ based application in Vala, which should be able to select a folder and then list the files inside it.

I've been able to select a single file using the Gtk.FileChooserDialog but I haven't found how to select a folder instead of a file.

Is there any way to tell the Gtk.FileChooserDialog that folders can be selected or is there any other widget to select folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`action`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.FileChooser.action.html) property.

`filechooser.action = FileChooserAction.SELECT_FOLDER;`